# Python, csv.writer, need to format output

Tags: python-2.7, csv, format

I am using Python 2.7 and am connecting to DB2 Z/OS db.
The output I am writing to a csv is not formatted correctly, for example, timestamp observations are wrapped in datetime.datetime(), decimals are wrapped in decimal() and char/varchar observations are preceeded by a u'.  Not sure how to resolve the problem, any ideas? -thanks

```
opfile  = open('dump.csv','w')
dump_writer = csv.writer(opfile)
ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(conStrg,"","")
conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(ibm_db_conn)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
dump_writer.writerow([row])
```